# Mysql alter a primary key column that has a relationship with another table

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

Could I change a primary key column that has a relationship in another table to be auto increment.

this is my code

```
 alter table sales_agreement modify column client_id int(11)  auto_increment ;
```

but I get error:-

```
 Cannot change column 'Client_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'Relationship5' of table ' order_sheet'
```

**Edit**
 Sales_Agreement  Table

```
    CREATE TABLE  Sales_Agreement
    (

      Client_id Int NOT NULL,
      Client Varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Client_id)
    ) ;
```

Table order_sheet

```
 CREATE TABLE Sales.Order_Sheet
(
  Client_id Int NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE Sales.Order_Sheet ADD PRIMARY KEY (Client_id)
;

ALTER TABLE Order_Sheet ADD CONSTRAINT Relationship5 FOREIGN KEY (Client_id) REFERENCES Sales_Agreement (Client_id)  
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to drop foreign key first,

> ALTER TABLE `'Order_Sheet'` DROP FOREIGN KEY `'Relationship5'`;

and then alter table by modifying the primary key.

Comment: Can't DROP 'Relationship5'; check that column/key exists                              please look my edit.

Comment: Can you execute `alter table order_sheet drop foreign key Relationship5;` and try? Sorry, I mistook, foreign key is on `order_sheet` table. Should work now

Comment: ERROR 1062 (23000): ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: So, do you have any record with client_id=0? You can run `select * from Order_Sheet where Client_id=0;` Auto-increment on the column will not be allowed if we have 0 in that column